# I accidentally told Easeus partition manager to format Ubuntu, can I cancel this before it takes effect on my next reboot?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, easeus-partition-manager

I was using Easeus Partion Manager in Windows 7, and accidentally selected the partition that has Ubuntu installed on it to be formatted/deleted. When the computer restarted, I luckily, launched Ubuntu from Grub.

I know if I restart and select the Windows 7 option from the Grub Menu, Easeus will start the operation I requested (the formatting/deletion of the Ubuntu partition). Is there a way to cancel it from uninstalling Ubuntu?

(My DVD drive is inoperable, and I won't be able to use a flash drive to reinstall it.) So I'm hoping I can cancel Easeus from starting the operation.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a Windows problem, not a Ubuntu one.

To prevent EaseUS Partition Master to do its job when you boot into Windows, first boot into Safe Mode in Windows.  You can do this by pressing F8 when Windows boots.

When you are in Safe Mode, go to `C:\Windows` and delete a file named `EPMBatch.ept`.  The file is hidden, so you have to make hidden files visible by going to `Appearance and Personalization > Folder Options > View > Advanced Settings > Show hidden files, folders, and drives`.  Choose that option and delete the file.

After that, reboot your computer and EaseUS shouldn't do the operation you accidently did (deleting the Ubuntu Partitions).

Comment: Thank you. I know it's a Windows problem, but considering it was going to delete my Ubuntu partition, I figured the good people here would know of a way that I could save Ubuntu from an unwarranted demise!

Comment: @Undisclosed Glad to help! :)